# I have installed scikit-learm/sklearn. After running the python file this error is coming

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-learn

```
Scanning for .csv files in folder `Dataset`...

===> File to be labeled: SampleDataset.csv

-------> Generating reports based on the trained models...

---------------> Generating report based on classifier `Davidson` trained on dataset `Davidson`.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Classifiers/Davidson/DavidsonClassifier.py", line 334, in <module>
    test(args)
  File "Classifiers/Davidson/DavidsonClassifier.py", line 316, in test
    y_preds = loaded_model.predict(X)
  File "/home/root1/Desktop/btp/OnlineHarms-Metatool/newenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 120, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/root1/Desktop/btp/OnlineHarms-Metatool/newenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 418, in predict
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
  File "/home/root1/Desktop/btp/OnlineHarms-Metatool/newenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_base.py", line 88, in transform
    mask = self.get_support()
  File "/home/root1/Desktop/btp/OnlineHarms-Metatool/newenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_base.py", line 52, in get_support
    mask = self._get_support_mask()
  File "/home/root1/Desktop/btp/OnlineHarms-Metatool/newenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_from_model.py", line 189, in _get_support_mask
    estimator=estimator, getter=self.importance_getter,
AttributeError: 'SelectFromModel' object has no attribute 'importance_getter'
---------------> Generating report based on classifier `Davidson` trained on dataset `Founta`.
```

**Is there some package that is missing or is it a version error?**

---

Here is a github repo link of ml model:-https://github.com/yashnatani28/OnlineHarms-Metatool

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well, and in your case as well it's most likely due to a version mismatch. try reinstalling `scikit-learn` with `pip install scikit-learn --upgrade` (or fix the version you want, but greater than 0.24 – `importance_getter` is an attribute introduced in version 0.24).